# Glassfish 4(development build) + eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, glassfish, eclipse-juno

I am trying some of the new features which are only available in Glassfish4(development build). 
My current eclipse plugin does not allow me to connect to glassfish4 - there's no 4.x version in the list.

Is there any way I can make it work? I would like to deploy/start the app from eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an Eclipse that is older than Juno... you cannot work with GlassFish 4.

If you have Juno, you can install a plugin that allows you to register GlassFish 4 server run-times. BE SURE TO READ https://blogs.oracle.com/piotrik/entry/new_version_of_glassfish_eclipse before you attempt to update your current GlassFish plugin.  If you do not have a GlassFish plugin installed in Juno, you can probably ignore almost all of the content of that page.

If you have Kepler M6 installed, you can try out the GlassFish server adapter (GFSA) and the GlassFish 4 run-time plugin (GF4RTP).  The GFSA is available here: http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/kepler

The latest update of the GFSA for Kepler should play nicely with the Java EE 7 features that got integrated into Kepler's milestone 6 release.

The GF4RTP is available here: 
http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/kepler/runtime

NOTE: all the bits available under download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/* are developer stream bits.  They are not 'production quality' and are being made available to get feedback from users willing to give them a try.  If you have to do something critical, you may want to wait for bits that will be integrated into the Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I have juno (already updated the initial post).
I will give it a try today!